# What is the best approach to implement bluetooth connectivity with multiple devices in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service

I have to implement bluetooth connectivity with multiple devices(4 devices) from my android java application. App will be continuously receiving data from 2 connected BT (bluetooth) devices, the other 2 BT devices can be connected on need basis & no need to maintain continuous connection. As per the requirements, app has to run continuously for 24 to 48 hours. The device with the app installed will be dedicatedly used for the app & the app will be continuously pushing the bluetooth received data to a remote server. The connected BT devices can be disconnected & reconnected any time from the app. Also if the BT connection is lost, automatic reconnect should happen. What is the best approach to implement this?

Comment: take a look at this http://arissa34.github.io/Android-Multi-Bluetooth-Library/

Answer (score 2):

Hi i have developed a similar app for BLE Heart rate Belts (Polar H7)

what i did (may not be the best approach but it works smoothly for me as i am able to mangae 5-7 belts at a time) is i made a service to manage the connection with multiple BLE devices
in the service i keep record of all the GATT Callbacks.

so i am using one service in backgorund to keep and mange the connections and separate GATT callbacks for each device in a list or Hashmap .

If a device disconnects or new connection needs to be established i connect/disconnect accordingly and update my record of GATT callbacks .

take a look at the [Android BLE sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/cefd49aae65dc85161d08419494071d74ffb982f/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeService.java) something similar

Comment: are you able to run the app for more than 24 hours with this approach ?

Comment: yes because even if the service gets destroyed i restart it and connect immediately to previous devices.this happens rarely because this phonae is dedicated for the app purpose only

Comment: are you using a single dedicated service for all the BT devices ? thn how you are managing the connection lost errors? If a BT device is automatically getting disconnected, are you restarting the service ?

Comment: yes 1 service for all of them and i have broadcastReceiver in my service to get connect and disconnect updates on devices .from ther i manage everything and i dont restart my service for this